# Does continuous function have primitive?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ be a continuous function,where $\Omega$ is an open set.I want to know whether $f$ will have a primitive or not.By primitive I mean a holomorphic function $F:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\in \Omega$.I want to know this because in case of Riemann integration we had seen that $f
:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ has antiderivative if $f$ is continuous.I want to know whether this theorem can be generalized.

Comment: No. Take $\Omega=\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: the derivatives of holomorphic functions are holomorphic, so $F'=f$ implies $f$ holomorphic; then if given $f$ holomorphic, it depends on the domain and $f$

Comment: It is ok if the domain $\Omega$ is simply connected.